# Libcurl unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, curl, visual-c++

So, I am trying to successfully compile libcurl (VC10 with openssl) in my project but I am getting a ton of errors (100+).
[image: errors]
This is what I did, step-by-step:

1. downloaded the latest curl
2. downloaded precompiled openssl for VC10 http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/
3. moved libeay32 and ssleay32 to src in curl's VC10 project folder
4. compiled libcurl.lib (LIB Release - LIB OpenSSL)
5. added CURL_STATICLIB to my preprocessor definitions
6. linked libcurl.lib with my VC10 project.

What am I missing??

Comment: Should I try building the openssl libraries myself? That's the only thing I haven't tried.

Comment: Nope, same errors.